# Expresso Store - How to use the checkout tag without any items in the cart?

Tags: expresso-store, checkout

I would like to use the {exp:store:checkout} tag to amend a members details such as order_email, shipping_country etc on an account page. Members fields are all setup being mapped to the correct place.

However, when viewing the account page (using the checkout tag) it will only show the member fields for editing when there is something in the shopping cart. I want to be able to show these details when there is nothing in the cart.

It must be possible, any ideas please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Store checkout tag to alter member profile fields. For that, you should use Freemember or another member management plugin.

The checkout tag will automatically load any mapped member fields, and save them when the customer submits an order, but you cannot use it to update member fields without placing an order.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adrian. I'm now using Freemember to update the member details in the account page. The issues I had previously were related to the shipping country not working correctly when the user updated it on the 1st checkout stage. The delivery and tax values were not correctly updating, but I have since ironed that out.

Answer (score 2):

Store doesn't deal with member details outside of the checkout. For that you'd need to use the default [Member module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html) with custom profile fields or take advantage of [Freemember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) (also made by Exp:resso so the integration should be good). FreeMember mainly just provides an easier way to deal with member profiles by releasing them from the shackles of default Member Profile Templates.

Going one better a specialist member addon such as [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) or [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) can be very useful if you really want to take control of Members and profiles in more detail, bringing those entries into regular Channels. Zoo Visitor may have a little better integration with Store and I've successfully used it in combination with Store to profile a member management in the past.

The good thing is that there is a tight integration between Store and Zoo Visitor so you can register new members in the checkout and have them added to your Members Channel. The other big bonus is that it brings member management into regular EE channels so you can work with regular templates and template tags.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for taking the time to reply. I have tried using Freemember but it just doesn't seem to work correctly with all fields. I have spoken with support at Expresso and they said it's possible to manage the member fields using the checkout tag. However due to the time difference (UK and New Zealand) I am trying to get an answer before I hear back from them.

Comment: Hey Wes. Hmmm, I know you can register new members within the checkout using Store and I know you can store order data to member profile fields but as far as recalling the member details in the accounts section I'm pretty sure you'd either have to use Member Profile Templates or use Freemember to pull out the member details. Can you show your code for the bit that isn't working?